# Excecuting methods within a Django project context? - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need to execute e few methods within my Django project's context, in order to work with Models.

I know commands exists, but I would like to import these methods and execute them within Python code.

---

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You only need to set your PYTHONPATH and DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variables prior to calling the python interpreter. From then on you can import your models, call their methods, etc...

```
export PYTHONPATH="...include your site's apps path..."
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="mysite.settings"
python
>>> from myapp.models import MyModel
>>> MyModel.objects.all()
...
```

Comment: Thank you! What if I have multiple projects? Is it necessary to create a dedicated user for each Django project?

Comment: I guess that's really up to you, how you organise your user accounts, and whether your projects use the same user database or separate ones, whether your apps require specific sets of permissions, etc... If you want to use a single shared user account for this purpose it is also possible (if your projects share the database for the user accounts and permissions).

Comment: not working :( I'm getting a few import errors from models.py files throughout my app

Comment: Can you provide some more details? Are you sure your PYTHONPATH/sys.path is correct? Check the note "Bypassing manage.py" here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#playing-with-the-api  BTW: as a side note, using virtualenvs could be a good way to ensure your python environment is appropriate and contains all dependencies

Answer (score 2):

Most of my commandline (and cron) scripts look something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from django.core.management import setup_environ
import settings
setup_environ(settings)
from django.db import transaction

... code ...

# you need to do the followng before exit if you did any DB changes.
transaction.commit_unless_managed()
```

**Update for comments:**

If you have made any saves/other changes, then my (possibly somewhat out of date) answer is Yes. I don't know if it is still required in the latest-stable release, but I'm sort of a belt-and-suspenders person when it comes to my database. I see `transaction.commit_unless_managed()` at the end of my scripts as a sort of safety net: If managed mode is in effect then it is a NOP, if it *isn't* then this makes sure the commit happens.

Comment: thank you! is the transaction commit also necessary if I use Django's ORM?